# How can I change Django admin language?

Tags: python, django, django-i18n

I have a django 1.6 site with i18n working. I can change the frontend language with a select box in the top of the template, but I don't know if there is a django app or trick to change the admin language, because it seems to store somewhere in session variable, and it keeps the first language I have used in the frontend.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create `/en/admin`, `/fr/admin/` and so on using [`i18n_patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns):

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

(For Django <= 1.7, you must specify a prefix, use `i18n_patterns('', ... )`)

Comment: it changes my application language correctly. but it dosent change the language file i also provided. how can i load that language  ? can you help me ? [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102538/language-file-dosent-load-automaticaly-in-django) @Udi

Answer (score 33):

In your settings.py just add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting, making sure it appears after `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`.

Comment: I wonder, why it was downvoted. That's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: Nice answer, it's easy and it works, but how can an user change the language? Depending on the language set in browser is not always a good solution.

Comment: Adding .locale.LocaleMiddleware is the only one thing which is necessary. Then admin will be in the language which is most preferred in the users browser setting.

Comment: of course for model entries inside admin you need more; you need use gettext_lazy() in model.py for such entries (or ugettext_lazy prior to dj2.0), then create .po file (./manage.py makemessages -l de_DE), translate it with poedit, compile the .po file (./manage.py compilemessages)

Answer (score 15):

Here is a slightly modified version of a code snippet from the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) for `admin/base.html` that adds a language selection dropdown:

```html
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block userlinks %}
{{ block.super }}
/ <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post" style="display:inline">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

For this to work you also need to add the following to your `urlpatterns`:

```py
path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

Comment: This solution is very useful if you want to see changing languages and translation results. I needed to add `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` after `SessionMiddleware` and I have added code above to (locally created app and that app put before `admin`) `templates/admin/base_site.html`

Comment: The code snippet is missing the following at the top:  

`{% extends "admin/base.html" %}  
{% load i18n %}`

Answer (score 1):

Change your browser default language.

Instead of spoiling the code. E.g.,
Chrome -> Settings -> Language -> Preferred languages: move upper Language you need.

Refresh browser, and the admin panel will change the displayed language.